# Error "Reverse for 'login' not found" when creating url path in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, url

I'm new to Django, and today when I tried to publish my Django application to Heroku, I always encountered an error

```
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I know where I'm wrong. The problem came in urls.py, so here is my code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('users.urls', 'login')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('jet/', include('jet.urls', 'jet')),
    path('citizens/', include('citizens.urls', namespace='citizens')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
    #path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    
]
```

Here is my urls.py inside users:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
app_name = 'users'
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    
]
```

In my project, the login page stay at URL "127.0.0.1:8000/users/login". It means when you typed only "127.0.0.1:8000/users", the page will notice an error: **Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.**

I want my path will directly go to users/login, but I don't know how to do it.
I have tried

```
path('', include('users.urls', 'login')),
```

or

```
path('', include('users.urls/login', namespace='users')),
```

or

```
path('', include('users.urls.login', namespace='users')),
```

but nothing works.

Thank you.

Comment: try ```namespace='users'```

Comment: Can you explain more? I have tried "path('', include('users.urls.login', namespace='user'))," but it won't work.

Comment: Have you tried ```users``` instead of ```user```

Comment: Yes, It returns "ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'users.urls.login'; 'users.urls' is not a package"

Comment: @hoangphi01 you likely either have some line like `reverse('login')` or `reverse_lazy('login')` or a line in the template like `{% url 'login' %}`. In all of these `login` needs to be replaced by `users:login` as you have _namespaced_ the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your app name is `users`

```
path('', include('users.urls/login', namespace='users')),
```

Change path to

```
path('', include('users.urls', namespace='users')),
```

To access the page via browser

> http://localhost:8000/login

In the templates, this URL should be referred as

```
{% url 'users:login' %}
```

In views it should be

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("users:login"))
```

Comment: I have tried this command at first time, but it doesn't work. You can check it here: https://secret-gorge-93845.herokuapp.com/
Because my login page is /users/login, not only /users/.

Comment: @hoangphi01 see the last part of the answer, make sure you have changed the path in project  urls.py as I mentioned in the answer.